# How to fix angular directives order (difference between Firefox and other browsers)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I'm using [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) timepicker on one input field. I needed to add some actions on timepicker hide event, so following [timepicker docs](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/), I've created a directive which does that:

```
.directive('onTimeHide', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.timepicker().on('hide.timepicker', function(e){

        // my code

      });
    }
  };
});
```

It works as expected under Chrome and Safari, but there is a problem with Firefox, timepicker widget is not being shown/opened. Appropriate dom elements for widget are added to the code, but functionality is not working.

After some debugging I found out that in Firefox my directive 'on-time-hide' is called before 'bs-timepicker', while in other browsers it's the opposite order.

I will be grateful for any suggestions how to fix that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `priority` key. In your case:

```
.directive('onTimeHide', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: -1, // for example
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.timepicker().on('hide.timepicker', function(e){

        // my code

      });
    }
  };
});
```

By default its `0` but if you want to load it second, set `-1`

Comment: wow! thanks, I haven't known about priority option - do you know if there is a doc where I could get more info on this? official one doesn't seem to be helpful...

Comment: I suggest you to read this good post about directives (and priority): http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive/